# How do I convert a disassembled instruction to be shown in binary in gdb?

Tags: binary, gdb

I've got a binary that I've disassembled into viewable assembly in gdb. However, I'd like to see the actual binary of each instruction (i.e. the actual instruction in whatever instruction format it is actually issued to the CPU in). Is there a way to input the address of an instruction and see that instruction in binary?

I tried p /t 0x-------- for whatever address, but it decoded the address itself into binary.
I tried the same, but with $0x--------, this produced a "Value can't be converted to integer" error.

I'd just like to be able to see an instruction such as lwi or ori at a given address, such as 0x00000300, in binary as gdb is seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `disassemble/r 0x...`.

From the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html):

```
print the raw instructions in hex as well as in symbolic
form by specifying the /r modifier.
```

**Update:**

> I can see, in layout asm, the assembly instructions obtained from my binary. But running the disassemble command on its own does not allow me to see anything, as it says "No function contains specified address."

So your binary is stripped (or at least GDB doesn't know where the nearest function is).

The solution is to disassemble just the instruction you are interested in. For example:

```
(gdb) disas 0x0000555555556d60
No function contains specified address.

(gdb) disas 0x0000555555556d60,+1
Dump of assembler code from 0x555555556d60 to 0x555555556d61:
   0x0000555555556d60:  mov    %edi,%eax
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disas/r 0x0000555555556d60,+1
Dump of assembler code from 0x555555556d60 to 0x555555556d61:
   0x0000555555556d60:  89 f8   mov    %edi,%eax
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: This states "no function contains the specified address" when I try to run this on the given address. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Using the 2-argument version disassemble /r 0x00000300, +16 doesn't do anything.

Comment: @FairtimeIA `0x00000300` is very unlikely to be an address of a valid instruction (unless your binary is linked to load at address 0).

Comment: Was only using that example, the real addresses are mostly in the 0xfff----- range.

Comment: @FairtimeIA I don't understand. If you can `disas 0xFFF...`, then `disas/r 0xFFF...` will give you raw bytes for the instruction (which I think is what you asked for). Using `disas 0x00000300` makes no sense.

Comment: I can see, in layout asm, the assembly instructions obtained from my binary. But running the disassemble command on its own does not allow me to see anything, as it says "No function contains specified address." Again, I can see the assembly instruction itself, but I want to see the raw binary of the instruction. I was only using the value 0x00000300 as a placeholder on here to show what command I was running as I couldn't think of the actual address I was really using off the top of my head.

Comment: That command doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't output anything for me. Is there maybe a file it's outputting to by default?

Comment: @FairtimeIA We are going in circles :-( Please edit your question with *actual* command you tried. You could also try `address,+4` instead of `address,+1` and see if that's better.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was to write the following command:

p /x *[hex address]

So for example:

p /x *0x00000300